# Getting HTTP 401 Error When Trying to Send Email Notifications in Google Composer

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I am trying to set up email notifications in Composer but for a Private Composer instance, following the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_sendgrid_email_services

The 'how-to' page does note that "Note: If your Cloud Composer environment is configured for Private IP, make sure that it has connectivity to the API endpoint for your external email service (such as https://api.sendgrid.com, or your preferred SMTP server)."

To test it out, in Google Cloud, I created an VPC Egress firewall rule for all targets and all ports, with an IP range of 0.0.0.0/0.

I have also set up a Sendgrid account, confirmed single sender verification for the email I'm sending it out from (same domain), and set IP access management to allow 0.0.0.0.

Lastly, I input the necessary information in the Airflow config file.

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.contrib.utils.sendgrid.send_email
SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM = [my-email@domain.com]
SENDGRID_API_KEY = SG.[***]

[smtp]
smtp_host = smtp-relay.gmail.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = [my-email@domain.com]
smtp_port = 587
smtp_password = [*****]
smtp_mail_from = [my-email@domain.com]
```

However, when I run the DAG to send an email, I still get an error  `WARNING - Failed to send out email with subject Airflow Alert, error: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`

Is there something I would need to do for a private Composer instance that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: If you directly edit the airflow config file the changes might not be reflected properly on the airflow web server. Can you try following [creating/updating variables](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables#adding_and_updating_environment_variables) and [overriding configurations](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/overriding-airflow-configurations#existing-env)?

Comment: Thanks Ricco, updating the environmental variables as per the Composer official instructions (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_sendgrid_email_services) was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

---

Resolved by changing the **environment variables** as per the instructions and not the config file directly.

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_sendgrid_email_services